# NestJs y TypeORM: Error al abrir el archivo DataSource

Tags: nodejs, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación usando NestJs y TypeOrm. Al inentar generar una migración obtengo el error:

`Error during migration generation: Error: Unable to open file: ".../src/config/data.source.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module at CommandUtils.loadDataSource`

Ya he ejecutado con anterioridad una migración, sin embargo ahora ya no me permite generar nuevos archivos de migraciones de mis nuevas entidades.

El archivo de configuración

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { join } from 'path';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { MysqlConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlConnectionOptions';

ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
});

const env = new ConfigService();

export const DataSourceConfig: MysqlConnectionOptions = {
  type: env.get('DB_TYPE'),
  host: env.get('DB_HOST'),
  username: env.get('DB_USERNAME'),
  password: env.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
  database: env.get('DB_DATABASE'),
  port: env.get('DB_PORT'),
  entities: [join(__dirname, '/../**/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}')],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, '/../migrations/*{.ts, .js}')],
  synchronize: true,
  migrationsRun: true,
  logging: false,
};
```

Archivo **app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { join } from 'path';
import { DataSourceConfig } from './config/data.source';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ ...DataSourceConfig }),
    UserModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Los comandos de migración:

```
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./src/config/data.source.ts",
"m:g": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run typeorm migration:generate",
"m:r": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run typeorm migration:run"
```

Comment: Tal vez esto te pueda ayudar [migration cli commands: migration:show, migration:run not working · Issue #9104 · typeorm/typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9104)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como estas? Esto puede pasar por varias razones, pero para la mas común te dejo la explicación acá:

```
npm i common-js
```

***Luego cambia en tu package.json el comando de migracion siguiente:***
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./src/config/data.source.ts",

por este:

```
"typeorm": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/config/data.source.ts",
```

Saludos espero que funcione correctamente